# Reverse routing in play framework 2.4.x

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to make possible to place link for one application within templates of another one. 
So I created three vals in build.sbt:

```
lazy val common: Project = (project in file("modules/common"))
    .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, PlayScala)
    .settings(aggregateReverseRoutes := Seq(admin, web))
    .settings(routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator)

lazy val admin = (project in file("modules/admin"))
    .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, PlayScala)
    .dependsOn(common)

lazy val web = (project in file("modules/web"))
    .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, PlayScala)
    .dependsOn(common)
```

I renamed routes file in `admin/conf` and `web/conf` to `admin.routes` and `web.routes` respectively.

How can I place link in, say, web project to admin project? 
Also, should I keep plain forward routing in projects admin and web?

Answer (score 1):

There is an aggregateReverseRoutes setting that will let you do this. Just add this setting to your web project.

```
lazy val admin: Project = (project in file("modules/admin"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, PlayScala)
  .dependsOn(common)

lazy val web: Project = (project in file("modules/web"))
  .enablePlugins(PlayJava, PlayEbean, PlayScala)
  .dependsOn(common)
  .settings(aggregateReverseRoutes := Seq(admin))
```

Comment: I am sorry, I added it already, but copied from another source). My problem is - how now should I call routes from another project in my scala templates? Could you point me to a direction?